# MAGENTO - Grid view not displaying as a grid

Tags: magento, view, grid

I have my magento to show as a grid but it is doing somthing rather strange. If you look at the webpage http://www.theshirt.org you will see that it shows 3 products then on the next row it shows 1, than 3 then 1 and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number of columns per row is set to 4, you need to change it to 3

Go to /app/design/frontend/default/[theme]/layout/catalog.xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
    ....
    <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>5</columns></action>
               ....
```

Change line to

```
   <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
```